# Origen test_ids gem questions

Tags: origen-sdk

I am evaluating using the [test_ids gem](https://github.com/Origen-SDK/test_ids) and had a few questions:

1. Can test numbers be left un-configured, only configuring bins and softbins?
2. Can the test interface query another object for the TestId config?  We have lots of test modules that have standardized hardbins but the softbins are always product specific due to test count variance.  Would like to have the test interface query the current active test module for the binning config.
3. Can you explain why there are 3 'b's in the softbin config?  Seems like you would only need one to create 100, 200, and 300.

   config.softbins = :bbb00

thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) I think so, if it doesn't work it should. If you don't configure the test numbers in the TestIds config then it should not generate a test number.

2) Sure, up to application logic how to select between the different configs. It is definitely intended to work like that though. The goal of this plugin is to allow you to write a test flow which is bin/test number agnostic, then depending on what TestIds config you generate it with you can have completely different numbering schemes being output.

3) You would only need one in that case, its just saying that potentially the bin can be between 1 and 999, and from memory I think it will raise an error if it encounters a bin > 999 when presented with a config like that with only 3 places allocated.